# How to delay execution within loop? Maybe NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am using `for` loop, in that I'm using `else if` conditions. In one of the `else if` I want to continue the `for` loop with some delay. Is it possible to use continue statement in `NSTimer`? If it is possible, how can I use continue statement in `NSTimer`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<[array count];i++){

    else if (condition)
    {
    }
    else if (condition)
    {
    }
    else if (condition)
    {
    }
    else if (condition)
    {
       // Here I want to continue the for loop with some delay
    }
    else if (conditions)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }

}
```

Please any one help me

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSThread sleepUntilDate:` and `NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:` to delay.

Example:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

    [NSThread sleepUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];
    NSLog(@"Delaying");

}
```

Output:

```
15:57:46.383 Delaying
15:57:47.386 Delaying
15:57:48.388 Delaying
15:57:49.389 Delaying
15:57:50.391 Delaying
```

Comment: My time intervals are like this 0.006125 0.00535
0.006128
0.00673
0.006082
0.006125
0.006175
0.005619
0.006389
0.005749
0.006406
0.00639
0.008703 Because of app going to sleep my application gets very slow. Can you have any other solutions please.

Comment: Simply run the code above in another thread, this way the interface remains responsive. You can delay any interval you like, for example `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.006125]` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you'd want to pauze the thread rather than use NSTimer. So something like the following in your if statement:

[NSThread sleepforTimeInterval:];
continue;

Comment: My time intervals are like this 0.006125 0.00535
0.006128
0.00673
0.006082
0.006125
0.006175
0.005619
0.006389
0.005749
0.006406
0.00639
0.008703 Because of app going to sleep my application gets very slow. Can you have any other solutions please.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use sleep(<#sleep duration#>);